# Bad excess code for an array setter

Tags: ios, nsarray, setter

I have an array of type NSArray as below:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myArray;
```

In the setter of this array, I want to check if the array count is 0, then return nil else return the array as it is. I am doing it as below:

```
- (NSArray *)myArray
{
    return ([self.myArray count] == 0) ? nil : self.myArray;
}
```

I am not getting any build error if I return nil for an NSArray, but its giving me run time error of bad access code. What mistake am I making here?

Comment: Okay solution - ([myArray count] == 0) ? _myArray = nil : (_myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:myArray]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getter method is recursively calling itself, because

```
self.myArray
```

is translated by the compiler to

```
[self myArray]
```

This causes a stack overflow (!) eventually.

Inside a setter or getter method of a property, you have to access
the associated *instance variable* instead, e.g.

```
- (NSArray *)myArray
{
    return ([_myArray count] == 0) ? nil : _myArray;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to set _myArray to myArray? Something like _myArray = myArray in its setter? Otherwise _myArray would always be nil or of count 0

Comment: @tech_learning: The `myArray` method is the *getter* method for the `myArray` property, not the *setter*, as you wrote in your question. Of course the array has to be allocated somewhere, but that has nothing to do with the *getter*. Perhaps you can explain better what you want to achieve.

Comment: So in my setter, I am doing _myArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:myArray]; I am getting an error here as "Use of undeclared identifier _myArray"

Comment: Is my setter wrong here? Is there a different syntax to handle the setter of an array?

Comment: @tech_learning: That's because you have implemented both *setter and getter* method. In that case the compiler does not synthesize the property and you have to do it explicitly: `@synthesize myArray = _myArray;`.

Comment: Alright gotcha... I actually wanted it in setter but I was trying to return the updated array. But it should work if I just set the array.

Comment: Thats what I am doing now finally ([myArray count] == 0) ? _myArray = nil : (_myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:myArray]);

Answer (score 0):

Do you instantiate the array anywhere else prior to calling this method? It will have to exist before you can access it.

```
_myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one",@"two",nil];
```

or one of the many other techniques to create an Array.